# how to clear cache of response header if the content(image) changed in asp.net

Tags: javascript, image, httphandler

In my project i have cached using response headers ,
mentioned as below:

```
  sMemooryStream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);

   context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(24));
   context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
   context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
```

Now the image has been chached sucessfully. But when i change some cached file  content the browser  is loading  the cached version of the file but expected is to get the latest file and not from the browser cahce how do i do it any help would b appriciated

Comment: Add your client-side code. so that it will easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.
Once it's cached, it's cached.

And that's exactly why I don't like caching. 
What you can do is add a parameter to the url, like

```
http://www.whatever.com/images/myfile.jpg?no_cache=lastWriteTimeUTC
```